# How to plot out all the days of a month with placeholder days and actual reports

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5 app. In this app I am creating a controller endpoint that should output all the days in a selected month. I am going to use this for plotting out a grid in an Angular 6 app. This will be used to send in time reports in bulk (a whole month at a time). I want the user to be able to go back and edit their month but I also want them to be able to add multiple reports on one day.

Below is my code for plotting out the JSON-object I use on frontend to plot out the grid/form. It kind of works but there are two basic problems.

1. It is not sorted on date. First it displays the whole month days and then (since I merge) it displays the actual reports made on certain days.
2. It still shows empty days even on days I have at least one report on. I want to only show empty placeholder days IF there are no reports for that day.

**My code:**

```
def month
        month = {'attendances_attributes' => []}
        dates = []
        posts = []
        range = (DateTime.now.beginning_of_month .. DateTime.now.end_of_month)
        range.each do |date|
            hash = {
                    id: nil,
                    starts_at_date: date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                    starts_at_time: nil,
                    ends_at_date: date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                    ends_at_time: nil,
                    break: nil,
                    description: nil,
                }
                dates << hash
        end
        attendances = Attendance.where(starts_at: Date.today.beginning_of_month .. Date.today.end_of_month).pluck(:id, :starts_at, :ends_at, :description).map { |e| [ e[0], e[1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), e[2].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), e[3] ] }
        attendances.each do |post|
            hash = {
                    id: post[0],
                    starts_at_date: post[1],
                    starts_at_time: nil,
                    ends_at_date:  post[2],
                    ends_at_time: nil,
                    break: nil,
                    description: post[3],
                }
                posts << hash
        end
        output = dates + posts
        render plain: output.to_json, status: 200
    end
```

**The output**

```
[
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-01",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-01",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-02",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-02",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-03",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-03",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-04",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-04",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-05",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-05",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-06",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-06",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-07",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-07",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-08",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-08",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-09",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-09",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-10",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-10",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-11",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-11",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-12",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-12",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-13",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-13",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-14",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-14",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-15",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-15",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-16",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-16",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-17",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-17",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-18",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-18",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-19",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-19",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-20",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-20",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-21",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-21",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-22",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-22",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-23",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-23",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-24",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-24",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-25",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-25",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-26",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-26",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-27",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-27",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-28",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-28",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-29",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-29",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-30",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-30",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": null,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-31",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-31",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": null
},
{
"id": 126,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-01",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-01",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": "dd"
},
{
"id": 127,
"starts_at_date": "2019-08-01",
"starts_at_time": null,
"ends_at_date": "2019-08-01",
"ends_at_time": null,
"break": null,
"description": "yay"
}
]
```

**Example front end output**

[image]

So to recap. I want to plot out a whole month (day by day). I only want to show an empty placeholder day IF there is no report for that day. I must allow for one or more reports on a certain day.

Comment: There, what's an "empty day", what's the expected output?

Comment: Since I am using the JSON output to plot out a complete grid form for one month on the frontend I want to have an empty day in the JSON object if there are no reports on that day so there will be a form field for that day.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I have updated my question with the frontend output